# Sinon .callsFake() is not mocking the return of the function

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have the following code in my test file:

```js
const stub1 = sinon.stub('../path/to/module', '_myFunc');
stub1.callsFake(function() {
  console.log('223344');
});
```

Inside a `beforeEach` in `Mocha`, but when `_myFunc` gets called, it is not executing the `console.log`.

`_myFunc` is exported like this:

```
module.exports = {
  _myFunc
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:

`index.ts`:

```js
function _myFunc() {
  console.log('real implementation');
}
module.exports = {
  _myFunc
};
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';

const mod = require('./index');

describe('mod', () => {
  it('should stub function', () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub(mod, '_myFunc').callsFake(() => {
      console.log('223344');
    });
    mod._myFunc();
    expect(stub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
  mod
223344
    ✓ should stub function


  1 passing (8ms)
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57044971